# Survey database - multiple surveys with questions and answers

Tags: database, survey

My job is to design, develop, implement, and analyse surveys. I do this for an education institute to find out how the students feel about the organisation, their programme, course content, their teacher etc.

I have now been asked to come up with a survey database or framework. This is technically far beyond my knowledge!

The idea is to have all of the different surveys included in this database. Survey questions are to be sorted by groups (programme evaluation, organisation evaluation etc) and indexed by survey name, year etc. Then to have all of the results from the surveys in the database.

This way any member in the organisation can see: 1) what questions have been previously asked; 2) what were the responses (results); and to have 3) survey questions that have been 'pre-approved' which they can pick and choose from when they make their own survey.

I really have no idea where to start. My research (google, googlescholar) led me no where - properly because there are technical terms which I am not familiar with. 
I would appreciate some help on where to start looking for the answers (terms, or existing programmes/software or frameworks that tackle this).

Btw - I will not be developing this database, but I need enough information to help me develop a job description so that I can hire someone to work with me.

Regards,
Char

Answer (score 0):

take a Open source tool : limesurvey.org for a good example.

Actually what you asking can be done in a plugin in limesurvey

Then you can make a job offer with :

- PHP dev
- Yii framework know